# HighCharts Column Chart Spacing Between Columns

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a column chart using highcharts, I need to specify the width of the column and I am able to achieve that using the `plotOptions.column.pointWidth` property, after that I need to specify the distance between the columns in pixels, and I don't find anything in the API about it, I tried using `plotOptions.column.groupPadding` and `plotOptions.column.pointPadding` but they don't work if the column width is fixed. Please let me know how to achive that.

In addition to specifying the space between columns, I would like to give the columns a background color that spans the entire y-axis.

Do you mean something like in this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can set or fixed width for columns (as you are using) or floating width using groupPadding and pointPadding. Highcharts doesn't provide option to set fixed width for bars and between them. You can create an idea here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general